# Running A Function When The Browser Window Is Not Focused

Tags: javascript

How can I run a function when the browser window is not focused.
I need to remove some classes from some elements when the browser window is not focused.

```
 //I want to run removePlayingClass() function when browser window is not focused but this doesn't work.
    document.onblur = function() {removePlayingClass()};

    function removePlayingClass() {
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (buttons[i].classList.contains('bButtons')) {
                buttons[i].classList.remove('bButtons');
            }
            if (buttons[i].classList.contains('aButtons')) {
                buttons[i].classList.remove('aButtons');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ali, this is not how So works, Tell us what you have tried, post some of your code and then we can help you to fix it, no one will write a code for you,

Comment: Ok, thank you for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since originally writing this answer, a new specification has reached recommendation status thanks to the W3C. The [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) API (on MDN) now allows us to more accurately detect when a page is hidden to the user.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
```